# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'useState' of 'owl.hooks' as it is undefined. in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

web.assets_common.min.js:8 Error while loading @web_o2b_responsive/components/apps_menu/apps_menu.esm: Cannot destructure property 'useState' of 'owl.hooks' as it is undefined. TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'useState' of 'owl.hooks' as it is undefined.

I am trying when Js file is loaded then call template and show text on webresponsive module.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are having this issue on version 16 or later.

`useState` and the like now reside in `owl` (instead of `owl.hooks`), so try changing lines like `const { ..., useState, ... } = owl.hooks;` to `const { ..., useState, ... } = owl;`

Going forward, remember that:

```
const {
        onError,
        onMounted,
        onWillDestroy,
        useExternalListener,
        useRef,
        useState,
        useSubEnv,
        reactive,
    } = owl;
```